# Does the menu item ID ever change?

Tags: menus, navigation, id

Does the ID Wordpress gives each menu item ever change?

```
id="menu-item-1234"
```

I've linked to it within my CSS, however this will be no use if this ID may change, for instance when the page is updated.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress menus are their own Post Type ( [`nav_menu_item`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) ). Every time you add a new item to a menu it create a new "post" in the `nav_menu_item` post type and assigns it a new ID just as deleting and recreating a page removes / adds new ids.

This means the only way the Navigation Item ID will change is if the item is removed from the Menu. You'll never have overlapping `id`'s either. If that's an issue then it's not very reliable. A more suitable solution would be to use [pseudo](https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/) [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) such as:

- :nth-of-type(n)
- :first-child
- :last-child

[Some browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) may have trouble with Pseudo Selectors though ( old browsers ).